# load Fullcalendar from current date to 18 months

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datepicker, fullcalendar

I have requirement of full calendar which starts at past 15 days from current date and ends at 18 months from current date

If current date is 2016-02-15, calendar should render from 2016-02-01 to 2017-08-15, like we have 1 year view, i need 1 and half year view. Is this possible? If not, please suggeset other way. Hope you understand

[Right now seeing result like in this image, click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkgmK.png)

[Need result like in this image, click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZIoC.png)

I used this code

```
  <script>
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: JSON.parse(json_events),

    utc: true,
    theme :true,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

    header: {
        left: 'today prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaMonths'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaMonths',
    views: {
        agendaMonths: {
           type: 'timeline',
            duration: { months: 18},
           buttonText: '18 Months',

        }
    },
    defaultDate :dateFormat.setDate(dateFormat.getDate()-15),
    viewRender: function(view,element,currentView,cell) {
        var now = new Date();
         $("[data-date="+now.getFullYear()+"-"+addZero(parseInt(now.getMonth()+1))+"-"+addZero(now.getDate())+"]").css("background-color", "yellow");
                    var end = new Date();
                   var endback = new Date().setMonth(now.getMonth() - 17);
                    end.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 17); //Adjust as needed
                    //console.log(now +'---'+end+'--'+new Date(endback));
                    if ( end < view.end) {
                        $("#calendar .fc-next-button").hide();
                     }
                    else {
                        $("#calendar .fc-next-button").show();
                    }
                    if ( view.start < new Date(endback)) {
                        $("#calendar .fc-prev-button").hide();
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#calendar .fc-prev-button").show();
                    }
    }, 
    dayRender: function (date, cell) {
        var now = new Date();
        //now= now.getFullYear()+"-"+addZero(parseInt(now.getMonth()+1))+"-"+now.getDate()-15);
        now.setDate(now.getDate()-15);
        now=now.getFullYear()+"-"+addZero(parseInt(now.getMonth()+1))+"-"+now.getDate();
        date=date.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        //console.log(now+'==='+date);
        if (now > date) {
           // cell.css("background-color", "red");
        }

   },
        eventOverlap: false, // will cause the event to take up entire resource height
    resourceAreaWidth: '30%',
    resourceColumns: [
        {
            labelText: 'Room',
            field: 'title'
        },
        {
            labelText: 'Occupancy',
            field: 'occupancy'
        }
    ],
    resourceOrder: 'title', // when occupancy tied, order by title //-occupancy,title
    resources: [
        { id: 'a', title: 'Room A', occupancy: 40 },
        { id: 'b', title: 'Room B', occupancy: 40, eventColor: 'green' },
        { id: 'c', title: 'Room C', occupancy: 40, eventColor: 'orange' },
        { id: 'd', title: 'Room D', occupancy: 40 },
        { id: 'e', title: 'Room E', occupancy: 40 },
        { id: 'f', title: 'Room F', occupancy: 40, eventColor: 'red' },
        { id: 'g', title: 'Room G', occupancy: 40 },
        { id: 'h', title: 'Room H', occupancy: 40 },
        { id: 'i', title: 'Room I', occupancy: 50 },
        { id: 'j', title: 'Room J', occupancy: 50 },
        { id: 'k', title: 'Room K', occupancy: 40 },
        { id: 'l', title: 'Room L', occupancy: 40 },
        { id: 'm', title: 'Room M', occupancy: 40 }
    ],

    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,

    select: function(start, end, allDay, event, resourceId) {
        var oldDay = new Date(start);
        var toDay = new Date();
        Date.prototype.sameDay = function(d) {
          return this.getFullYear() === d.getFullYear()
            && this.getDate() === d.getDate()
            && this.getMonth() === d.getMonth();
        }
        if(oldDay.sameDay(toDay)) {
            console.log('event select oldDay.sameDay');
            createEvent(start,end,resourceId.id);
        }else{
            if(oldDay > toDay){
                console.log('event select oldDay > toDay');
                createEvent(start,end,resourceId.id);
            }else{
                alert("Cannot book for past days!");
            }
        }

    },

    eventClick: function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
        console.log('eventClick');
        //modifyEvent(event,'form');
    },
    eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
        var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" title= "' + calEvent.title + '" style="width:100px;height:50px;background:#ccc;position:absolute;z-index:10001;">' + calEvent.title + '</div>';
        $("body").append(tooltip);
        $(this).mouseover(function(e) {
            $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
            $('.tooltipevent').fadeIn('500');
            $('.tooltipevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
        }).mousemove(function(e) {
            $('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
            $('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
        });
    },

    eventMouseout: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
         $(this).css('z-index', 8);
         $('.tooltipevent').remove();
    },
    eventDragStart :  function( event,jsEvent ) { 
        console.log(jsEvent);


        $(this).addClass('somthing');
        $('.somthing').css("background-color", "yellow");
        eventDateStart  =event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        eventDateEnd  =event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        eventStatus = event.status;
    },
    eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
        console.log('eventDrop');

        var now = new Date();

        now=now.getFullYear()+"-"+addZero(parseInt(now.getMonth()+1))+"-"+now.getDate();
        var todayStart = event.start;
        var todayEnd = event.end;
        console.log('eventDragStart: '+eventDateStart+'---eventDateEnd: '+eventDateEnd+'----now: '+now+'----todayStart: '+todayStart.format('YYYY-MM-DD')+'---todayEnd: '+todayEnd.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        if(eventStatus == 1){
            alert("Guest has checked out, can't modify'");
            revertFunc();
        }else if( todayStart.format('YYYY-MM-DD') < now ){
            alert("can't change room less than today date");
            revertFunc();
        }else if(todayEnd.format('YYYY-MM-DD') < now  ){
            alert("can't change room less than today date");
            revertFunc();
        }else{
            if (confirm("Are you sure want to modify "+event.title + "Room Details?")) {
                moveEvent(event);
            }else{
                revertFunc();
            }
        }

   },
    eventResizeStart : function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ){
        console.log('eventResizeStart');
        eventDateStart  =event.start.format();
        eventDateEnd  =event.end.format();
        eventStatus = event.status;
    },
    eventResize: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view  ) {
        var now = new Date();
        now=now.getFullYear()+"-"+addZero(parseInt(now.getMonth()+1))+"-"+now.getDate();
        console.log('eventResize');
        var todayStart = event.start;
        var todayEnd = event.end;

        if(eventStatus == 1){
            alert("Guest has checked out, can't modify'");
            revertFunc();
        }else if(todayStart.format("YYYY-MM-DD") < now){
            alert("can't change room less than today date");
            revertFunc();
        }else{
            if (confirm("Are you sure want to modify "+event.title + "Room Details?")) {
                modifyEvent(event,'resize');
            }else{
                revertFunc();
            }
        }
    }

});
</script>
```

views: { 
        timelineDay: {
            type: 'timeline',
            duration: { days: 365 }
        }
    }

this works fine for me(my requirement is for 1 and half year) but when i add days 548/months 18 its loading only months not days

Please suggest me here

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? What language? Did you try something?

Comment: Please provide ruff snap to understand better.

Comment: If current date is 2016-02-15, calendar should render from 2016-02-01 to 2017-08-15, like we have 1 year view, i need 1 and half year view. Is this possible ? if not please suggeset other way. Hope u understand thanks

Comment: yes tried facing issues didnt find solution, Im using fullcalendar with php, mysql, jquery

Comment: if youre using a js package that draws the calendar on ui; you should be able to read the documentation and set your range.

Comment: Should duration be plural; `months` instead of `month`?

Comment: Tried this its only displaying months, i need days too, i have tried with agendaFourWeeks: {
           type: 'timeline',
           duration: { days: 548},
           buttonText: '18 Months',
           //fixedWeekCount : false
    }, Even though result same. Thanks

Comment: @unixmiah: You are right - but documentation found on project's web (www.fullcalendar.io) is simply terrible. I saw better ones (more explaining).

Comment: @drneel: Yes, it should. It is all I could read from project's documentation. But I am sure that it is not all what is needed to do.

Comment: views: { timelineDay: { type: 'timeline', duration: { days: 365 } } }, this works fine for me(my requirement is for 1 and half year) but when i add days 548/months 18 its loading only months not days Thanks

Comment: Found solution for this. I have added 538 days, with 538 days it's working fine if more than 538 days it's not working